# Is the empty set (or any analogy) ever non-unique?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I seems SO obvious that the empty set is unique, and yet every lecture on set theory and topology feels the need to state the proof. Why is that?

Usually if something seems completely obvious, but the lecturer still presents the proof, it is a tell-tail sign, that one is studying the special case without knowing, and the property isn't true in the general case.

Comment: Usually if something seems completely obvious, one should question one's assumptions. Doing so for set theory leads to profound developments, such as the Zermelo-Franiel axioms.

Comment: I've never once seen anyone prove the empty set is unique.  And many students who have trouble with the concepts of sets (not understanding how the empty set can be a subset of a non-empty set, and thinking that if a set is a subset it is also an element of the set) often don't see that the empty set is unique.

Comment: "Usually if something seems completely obvious, but the lecturer still presents the proof, it is a tell-tail sign, that one is studying the special case without knowing"  This is absolutely not at all my experience.  The *entire* point of mathmetics is to take things that are "completely obvious" and to formalize into well-defined axioms.  From that we *need* to prove the obvious to lay the axiomatic ground work.

Comment: A complete counter example is proving 1 > 0 or that if two paths and on opposite sides the must cross at some point, etc.  are most certainly NOT studying a special case and most certainly IS true in the general case.  Where on earth have you been studying mathematics that is so contrary to basic rigor?

Comment: I think proving that the emptyset is unique is a good piece towards demonstrating the *extensionality*, rather than *intensionality*, of set theory. The emptyset is possibly the most natural set given to lots of different intensional definitions: the set of counterexamples to Fermat and the set of primes with rational square roots are each the empty set, but clearly are different definitions. And for whatever reason, it's the set which seems to cause the most trouble in this regard. As trivial as it is, using the  axiom of extensionality here plants the seed of extensional thinking.

Comment: @fleablood I think you have misunderstood me. That is, precisely, because both of your examples are the special case: proving 1>0 makes only sense in the special case, in which the defined order on the set dictates the statement. In the very general sense, the statement is not obvious, since the order could dictate anything. And two lines on opposite lines must only cross if the lines are continuous, which, in the general case, the are not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question seems to ask about motivations of people which is not a mathematical question. However, consider a set theory which allows **urelements** (**atoms**), that is, objects which have no elements, yet are not the empty set. The standard proof of uniqueness of empty set does not apply to atoms. Also, consider the category of sets and functions. The empty set is an initial object in this category. Any initial object in any category is unique up to isomorphism. This is similar to the uniqueness of empty set in set theory.

Comment: Traditionally, atoms are not even sets. If you characterize atoms as objects without elements, then in set theories like ZFA, there is a unique atom which is also a set. So as far as examples go, this is not the best one. However, there are non-extensional set theories in which there can be many empty sets which are isomorphic, but not equal. ETCS is an example to that. (This is what Noah wrote in the comments to the main question about extensional thinking.)

Answer (score 14):

This is not really a question about the empty set as much as it is a question about mathematical education, culture, pedagogy, and practices.

The point being is twofold:

1. This is a very good example of showing a simple proof. We have some axioms, and we derive a consequence. This is a good way to exercise the students in how to approach a problem that seems obvious (which are usually very hard at first, because you don't know what you're supposed to do). This is a good exercise in understanding that proofs require you to understand the assumptions, their consequences, and what sort of routes one might take in order to verify these statements.
2. There is no absolute notion of "obvious". And it is important that mathematics is built on strong foundations. It used to be obvious that all numbers are ratios of two repeat sums of the unit; but then $\sqrt2$ happened to be irrational. History is rife with similar examples, where people made mistakes that would be considered very silly nowadays. But at the time, due to the fact that "obvious observations" were left unchecked (partially because culturally mathematicians didn't bother with very precise definitions from the ground up). So again, this is a prime opportunity for instilling some good values into students and teaching them that everything requires proof in mathematics.

Comment: Possible example of non-intuitionistic reasoning? If $A \neq B,$ then $A \cup B \neq \emptyset.$

Comment: I'm afraid I kinda lost you, Dave.

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are unequal sets, then at least one of them is not the empty set, hence their union is not the empty set. I'm not sure an intuitionist would accept this, but I don't really know.

Comment: Ah. Yeah, well, I'm definitely not the person to ask about intuitionism...

Comment: @Dave: My understanding is that constructive set theory will allow you to conclude that $A\cup B\ne \varnothing$ but not that $A\cup B$ has an element.

Comment: @Henning Makholm: This to me is a good example of why Eric Schechter titled his 2001 Amer. Math. Monthly paper [*Constructivism is difficult*](https://math.vanderbilt.edu/schectex/papers/difficult.pdf). Incidentally, we exchanged quite a few emails in the late 1990s to early 2000s about these issues, especially the non-constructive proof that an irrational to an irrational power can be rational --- did it originate from Hilbert or his students, given that one of the Hilbert problems was illustrated with whether $2^{\sqrt 2}$ is transcendental.  I've only traced it back to about 1966 or so.

Comment: Being skeptical of the obvious is good in mathematics, science, and honestly just daily life.

Comment: @corsiKa: I am skeptical about that.